# Migrate Angular 2 RC on live environment

Tags: angular

We are currently developing the web application in Angular 2 RC. Will it be feasible to upgrade the Angular when the final version releases over the air ? Means upgrade the Angular JS Framework without changing any code in  production environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, chances are you still have to do upgrades on code, as the angular2 team has been introducing last minute BC breaking changes in the latest RC releases. As long as there is no stable version, you won't get any guarantee that your code will still work in the next version.

Having said that, I do think it's wise to go along with the angular2 devs and upgrade directly, everytime a new release is introduced, to keep your maintenance work incremental and thus, easier to execute.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think we should go with Angular 1 for now.